# Can I write PostgreSQL functions on Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, function, rails-activerecord

We are starting a project based on Ruby on Rails. We used to work with Perl and PostgreSQL functions, and with Rails and Active Record I've not seen how we are supposed to create functions in PostgreSQL and keep the record with Active Record and models.

I know we can create it manually in PostgreSQL, but the "magic" with Active Record is that the database can be recreated with all the models.

Is there any way to create the PostgreSQL function using Rails and keep it in the models?

Comment: AFAIK there's no built-in way to write SQL functions via Rails, but depending on the functions, they might be better refactored as [scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) or other model methods.

Comment: However, you could simply write a class in the lib directory that defines SQL functions. You can execute arbitrary SQL via `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute`.

Comment: Are you looking for some kind of "PL/Ruby" with ActiveRecord support?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This part of your question:

> I know we can create it manually in PostgreSQL, but the "magic" with Active Record is that the database can be recreated with all the models.

tells me that you're really looking for a way to integrate PostgreSQL functions with the normal Rails migration process and Rake tasks such as `db:schema:load`.

Adding and removing functions in migrations is easy:

```
def up
  connection.execute(%q(
    create or replace function ...
  ))
end

def down
  connection.execute(%q(
    drop function ...
  ))
end
```

You need to use separate `up` and `down` methods instead of a single `change` method because ActiveRecord will have no idea how to apply let alone reverse a function creation. And you use `connection.execute` to feed the raw function definition to PostgreSQL. You can also do this with a `reversible` inside `change`:

```
def change
  reversible do |dir|
    dir.up do
      connection.execute(%q(
        create or replace function ...
      ))
    end
    dir.down do
      connection.execute(%q(
        drop function ...
      ))
    end
  end
end
```

but I find that noisier than `up` and `down`.

However, `schema.rb` and the usual Rake tasks that work with `schema.rb` (such as `db:schema:load` and `db:schema:dump`) won't know what to do with PostgreSQL functions and other things that ActiveRecord doesn't understand. There is a way around this though, you can choose to use a `structure.sql` file instead of `schema.rb` by setting:

```
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

in your `config/application.rb` file. After that, `db:migrate` will write a `db/structure.sql` file (which is just a raw SQL dump of your PostgreSQL database without your data) instead of `db/schema.rb`. You'll also use different Rake tasks for working with `structure.sql`:

- `db:structure:dump` instead of `db:schema:dump`
- `db:structure:load` instead of `db:schema:load`

Everything else should work the same.

This approach also lets you use other things in your database that ActiveRecord won't understand: CHECK constraints, triggers, non-simple-minded column defaults, ...

Comment: Another option: [F(x)](https://github.com/teoljungberg/fx) adds methods to ActiveRecord::Migration to create and manage database functions and triggers in Rails.
[F(x) gem](https://github.com/teoljungberg/fx)

Comment: Why not just put the function definitions in an initializer file and let git take care of versioning?

Comment: @DennisHackethal Then you'd be splitting the database definition into pieces that go in different places. You'd also end up having to replicate the migration versioning system unless you wanted to drop and recreate the functions every time the app starts up.

Comment: Since postgres functions can be replaced easily using `create or replace`, a replication of the migration versioning system doesn't seem to be required. Dropping all functions (and recreating some) only seems necessary if having functions left over that are no longer needed is a concern. For those interested, I've written up how to drop all user-defined routines [here](https://blog.dennishackethal.com/posts/how-to-delete-all-user-defined-routines-in-postg).

Comment: @DennisHackethal Hence the "unless you wanted to drop and recreate the functions every time the app starts up" part of my comment. I don't see the point of not using migrations (which manage database changes). Or do you have a problem with `structure.sql` rather than `schema.rb`? Also, what happens if you try to drop/replace a function that is used in a trigger, default value, index, CHECK constraint, ...?

Comment: I thought you were implying that replacing them each time would take effort. "Or do you have a problem with structure.sql rather than schema.rb?" That does sound like a decent amount of effort. Then again, maybe not more than what's in my article. "[W]hat happens if you try to drop/replace a function that is used in a trigger, default value, index, CHECK constraint, ...?" I don't know. Something bad, I'm guessing?

Comment: @DennisHackethal Well it does take effort because you have to manage all the things that might depend on the functions. Trying to drop a function that is used somewhere will raise an error, so yeah, bad stuff. The first thing I do with a Rails app is switch to `structure.sql` to make it easier to use everything that database has to offer; AFAIK this process is easier in Rails7.

Answer (score 1):

If your only requirement is creating them somewhere in your Rails app, this is possible through `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute`, which you can use to execute raw SQL queries.

```
stmt = 'CREATE FUNCTION...'
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute stmt
```

You would then call the function using `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` as well (I'd imagine you'd have methods in your model to handle this).