# Rails5 - How to db:setup new machine and include database autoincrement id sequences

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, migration, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Rails5 api that was built from scratch and all of my models' database sequences for id autoincrement where automatically created.  When a colleague attempted to db:setup the database on a fresh machine, the schema was loaded, but the sequences were not created and, therefore, our db:seeds were unable to be added because there is a "not null" constraint on the tables.

The original table id column looks like this

```
id  | integer | not null default nextval('users_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |
```

After running db:setup, the "new" database on the fresh machine looks like this

```
id  | integer | not null  | plain    |
```

I've never had this issue with previous Rails versions and wonder if it may be a v5 issue.  What are we doing wrong?

Thanks for any tips!!

On the new database, there are no sequences shown in postgres when running "\ds;"

The migration for the users table looks looks like this

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :first_name, limit: 25
      t.string :last_name, limit: 25
      t.string :mobile_phone, limit: 25
      t.string :auth_token, limit: 36
      t.integer :failed_login_attempts, limit: 2, :default => 0
      t.boolean :account_locked, :default => false
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

schema.rb for this table looks like this ( after some later migrations )

```
create_table "users", id: :integer, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "first_name",             limit: 25
    t.string   "last_name",              limit: 25
    t.string   "mobile_phone",           limit: 25
    t.string   "auth_token",             limit: 36
    t.integer  "failed_login_attempts",  limit: 2,  default: 0
    t.boolean  "account_locked",                    default: false
    t.datetime "created_at",                                           null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                                           null: false
    t.string   "email",                             default: "",       null:         
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
  end
```

Comment: What does `schema.rb` look like?

Comment: @muistooshort .. I added the schema.rb for this particular table above.

Comment: Does that `id: :integer` look wrong or at least suspicious to you? I switched to `structure.sql` long ago because I use things that ActiveRecord doesn't understand so I'm sure but that `id: :integer` smells wrong to me.

Comment: hm, my Rails4 projects don't do that either.  I'm not familiar with structure.sql, but will investigate it.  Any tips?

Comment: I wonder if there's been a regression in the version of Rails5 you used. Using `structure.sql` instead of `schema.rb` is pretty easy (there's a brief outline in http://stackoverflow.com/a/31955422/479863).