# Where I should put a complex sql on a rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I would like to know what is the best way to keep in maintenance and call a complex query due to using **Active Record** is not a good practice to call stored procedures and my query contains a temp table and several updates to fill such temp table.
I was thinking create a constant which store all query,however I have been seeing y many blogs that It's a bad practice to do that.

Regards

Comment: What's wrong with using a stored procedure? You'd want to switch from `schema.rb` to `structure.sql` for keeping track of your database of course. A lot of the "no logic in the database" you hear from Rails people is nonsense from people that are database-ignorant or language bigots that are afraid of anything that isn't Ruby (IMO).

Comment: I agree with you, creating a stored procedure is the most suitable solution for this case, however researching how to keeping track the database I found that stored procedure are not the best solution and is a bad practice but what I really care about is when other developer install the project It can create the stored procedure from schema or a migration, Is it possible do that?

Comment: IMHO store the SQL queries in `db/queries/*.sql`, write a class that is able to load and run the queries and define a nice interface like: `SQLQuery.new(query_name).execute(parameters)`. Having the query in a file means: benefit from version control and easier to read and maintain than stored procedures.

Comment: If you switch from using `schema.rb` to `structure.sql` (as in [**Can I write PostgreSQL functions on Ruby on Rails?**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31955422/479863)) then stored procedures, triggers, CHECK constraints, all sorts of other useful database things that ActiveRecord doesn't understand can be managed in the usual way. Going through contortions to avoid putting logic where it belongs (which is often inside the database) is pointless dogmatism.