# has_one association not working with includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I've been trying to figure out some odd behavior when combining a `has_one` association and `includes`.

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments

  has_one :latest_comment, -> { order('comments.id DESC').limit(1) }, class_name: 'Comment'
end

class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
end
```

To test this I created two posts with two comments each. Here are some rails console commands that show the odd behavior. When we use `includes` then it ignores the order of the `latest_comment` association.

```
posts = Post.includes(:latest_comment).references(:latest_comment)
posts.map {|p| p.latest_comment.id}
=> [1, 3]

posts.map {|p| p.comments.last.id}
=> [2, 4]
```

I would expect these commands to have the same output. `posts.map {|p| p.latest_comment.id}` should return `[2, 4]`. I can't use the second command because of n+1 query problems.

If you call the latest comment individually (similar to `comments.last` above) then things work as expected.

```
[Post.first.latest_comment.id, Post.last.latest_comment.id]
 => [2, 4]
```

If you have another way of achieving this behavior I'd welcome the input. This one is baffling me.

Comment: It seems you use wrong order. The scope you use `ASC` but your expectation use `p.comments.last.id` which actually is `DESC` order

Comment: I don't think you can do it that way. The `scope` argument for your `has_one` ends up in the join condition on the LEFT JOIN that your query produces (see `Post.includes(:latest_comment).references(:latest_comment).to_sql`) and ORDER BY makes no sense in a join condition so AR won't bother putting it in. If you try to make the scope instance-dependent (`->(post) { ... }`) to get the latest using a WHERE clause (which will be in the join condition) then you'll get an ArgumentError.

Comment: @yeuem1vannam - yes that should be DESC. I updated it.

Comment: @muistooshort - yep. that all makes sense. Is there any other way to do this?

This is my workaround for now, `Post.left_joins(:latest_comment).distinct`

Comment: You're sort of abusing `has_one` and its scope argument so it is only partially working. Which database are you using?

Comment: It's PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

I think the cleanest way to make this work with PostgreSQL is to use a database view to back your `has_one :latest_comment` association. A database view is, more or less, a named query that acts like a read-only table.

There are three broad choices here:

1. Use lots of queries: one to get the posts and then one for each post to get its latest comment.
2. Denormalize the latest comment into the post or its own table.
3. Use a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) to peel off the latest comments from the `comments` table.

**(1)** is what we're trying to avoid. **(2)** tends to lead to a cascade of over-complications and bugs. **(3)** is nice because it lets the database do what it does well (manage and query data) but ActiveRecord has a limited understanding of SQL so a little extra machinery is needed to make it behave.

We can use the `row_number` window function to find the latest comment per-post:

```
select *
from (
  select comments.*,
         row_number() over (partition by post_id order by created_at desc) as rn
  from comments
) dt
where dt.rn = 1
```

Play with the inner query in `psql` and you should see what `row_number()` is doing.

If we wrap that query in a `latest_comments` view and stick a `LatestComment` model in front of it, you can `has_one :latest_comment` and things will work. Of course, it isn't quite that easy:

1. ActiveRecord doesn't understand views in migrations so you can try to use something like [scenic](https://github.com/thoughtbot/scenic) or switch [from `schema.rb` to `structure.sql`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31955422/479863).
2. Create the view:

   ```
   class CreateLatestComments < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
     def up
       connection.execute(%q(
         create view latest_comments (id, post_id, created_at, ...) as
         select id, post_id, created_at, ...
         from (
           select id, post_id, created_at, ...,
                  row_number() over (partition by post_id order by created_at desc) as rn
           from comments
         ) dt
         where dt. rn = 1
       ))
     end
     def down
       connection.execute('drop view latest_comments')
     end
   end
   ```

   That will look more like a normal Rails migration if you're using scenic. I don't know the structure of your `comments` table, hence all the `...`s in there; you can use `select *` if you prefer and don't mind the stray `rn` column in your `LatestComment`. You might want to review your indexes on `comments` to make this query more efficient but you'd be doing that sooner or later anyway.
3. Create the model and don't forget to manually set the primary key or `includes` and `references` won't preload anything (but `preload` will):

   ```
   class LatestComment < ApplicationRecord
     self.primary_key = :id
     belongs_to :post
   end
   ```
4. Simplify your existing `has_one` to just:

   ```
   has_one :latest_comment
   ```
5. Maybe add a quick test to your test suite to make sure that `Comment` and `LatestComment` have the same columns. The view won't automatically update itself as the `comments` table changes but a simple test will serve as a reminder.
6. When someone complains about "logic in the database", tell them to take their dogma elsewhere as you have work to do.

---

Just so it doesn't get lost in the comments, your main problem is that you're abusing the `scope` argument in the `has_one` association. When you say something like this:

```
Post.includes(:latest_comment).references(:latest_comment)
```

the `scope` argument to `has_one` ends up in the join condition of the LEFT JOIN that `includes` and `references` add to the query. ORDER BY doesn't make sense in a join condition so ActiveRecord doesn't include it and your association falls apart. You can't make the scope instance-dependent (i.e. `->(post) { some_query_with_post_in_a_where... }`) to get a WHERE clause into the join condition, then ActiveRecord will give you an `ArgumentError` because ActiveRecord doesn't know how to use an instance-dependent scope with `includes` and `references`.