# Mysql2::Error: there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, schema

Trying to get a rails app up and running. I'm getting this error from the following table definition given in as schema.rb by a colleague.

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key
```

Table definition:

```
  create_table "wv latest", id: false, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "id", null: false, auto_increment: true
    t.string "cid", limit: 10
    t.integer "visit_id"
    t.string "cfname", limit: 20
    t.string "clname", limit: 25
  end
```

When I remove

```
auto_increment: true
```

The error goes away. Why is this happening and why does the schema not work in my setup?

Comment: That `create_table` is a bit odd. You have `id: false` (i.e. don't automatically create an auto incrementing `id` column as the PK) but then it almost creates what `id: false` keeps Rails from creating on its own. Are these tables from another application?

Comment: Yes I think. I'm just starting this job, and I'm pretty sure there are close to 20 years of legacy data in there. Haha. Fun fun.

Comment: If that's the case (and I don't doubt it), I wonder if you'd be better off with [`structure.sql` instead of `schema.rb`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31955422/479863). If there's history and Rails is yet another layer in the history then going with a raw schema dump from MySQL might work better than trying to shoehorn things into Rails.

Comment: I can look into that. The thing is that there already is a rails app connecting to this db, and that's where I got the schema.rb from. I just figured if it worked for that app, it should work for mine. Most everything is equivalent, rails version, mysql version. But perhaps the schema.rb and actual schema of the db got out of sync somewhere along the line.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that only column can be auto increment, *and* that this column must also be the primary key.  So, try making the `id` column the primary key:

```
create_table "wv latest", id: false, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "id", null: false, auto_increment: true, primary_key: true
    t.string "cid", limit: 10
    t.integer "visit_id"
    t.string "cfname", limit: 20
    t.string "clname", limit: 25
end
```

Comment: I've confirmed that the schema will load if I remove the auto_increment, or as you recommend, add primary_key: true. This issue in my case is I'm trying to connect a new app to share the database of another rails app. I'd have to ask the owner to add this to their db. Just not sure why it wouldn't work for me but would for them.

Comment: It could be due to a number of things.  Off the top of my head, your MySQL versions/configurations might be different.  From a design point of view, there is nothing wrong with enforcing this.