# What is the best way to call a Postgres stored function in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I've created a function in Postgres that I'd like to call from my Rails code. What is the best way to do that? Is there an ActiveRecord method I can use? Or do I need to use SQL, as in `Arel.sql`?

Comment: Did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31953498/5025116)?

Comment: There is no special method in ActiveRecord, you need to use SQL. You can just do something like `Post.connection.execute("select version();").first`

Comment: @nathanvda Thanks, I did that, but it was not enough to call `first`, as that returned a hash, from which I needed to extract my value; so I added `.values.first` to `first` because there was only 1 value returned. Would you like to post that as your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no special method in ActiveRecord, you need to use SQL. You can just do something like

```
Post.connection.execute("select version();").first 
=> {"version"=>"PostgreSQL 10.5 on x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0, compiled by Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2), 64-bit"}
```

This will return a hash per row where the keys are the column-names, and the values the corresponding values. So for this specific example, I know this will only return one row so I do `first` to retrieve the first row immediately. If you would just want to retrieve the version immediately, you could also write

```
version = Post.connection.execute("select version();").first.values.first 
=> "PostgreSQL 10.5 on x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0, compiled by Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2), 64-bit"
```